# Can I test OneSignal push notification on Expo platform?

Tags: react-native, expo, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I'm developing Mobile App for IOS and Android and using the Expo platform during development. In this way, simply with a QR code, I can test the application in seconds for both devices Android and IOS.

I'm going to implement OneSignal Push notification for my React-Native Expo project, But before doing that I want to be sure that I can keep using "expo start" command and develop applications easily instead of building on Android Studio or XCode.

Is it possible to test OneSignal push notification with Expo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer deep inside of https://docs.expo.io/introduction/why-not-expo/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should work. I have used Google Firebase for expo notification which worked fine in devlopment.

I didn't work with **One Signal**. But according to their docs it should work with expo. Check out more [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup)